# What QSPI chip is on ItsyBitsy M4 Express?

Tags: flash, atmel, board, qspi

I'm trying to find out the name of the QSPI chip that is used on ItsyBitsy M4 Express boards.
On the image below is very faded:
[image]

Comment: I see lots of chips, and two that are not so faded, which one are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

The schematic for this board is openly available on the adafruit website, and it gives the part number. You may need to dig a little.

Comment: the schematic say GD25x16 it doesn't give the name.

Comment: That's the part number right there. x is a wild card so just search up "GD25 memory". You get GigaDevices NOR Flash: https://www.gigadevice.com/products/memory/flash/spi-nor/

Comment: @DKNguyen thanks